# Is it possible to use vfsStream with cakephp (2.4)?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.4, realpath, vfs-stream

I wanted to test the filesystem operations of my cakephp-app using vfsStream, but had to find out that it is seemingly not possible to write files to the virtual filesystem using cakephp`s File and Folder classes. The reason for this seems to be the call to the php function realpath() in the constructor of the Folder-class. vfsStream seems to break when realpath() is used (see http://stubbles.org/categories/5-vfsStream - "realpath() still doesn't work - there is no way to make this work with how realpath() is currently implemented in PHP itself.")

It seems to be that I am out of luck or does any of you know a workaround this issue?

Comment: Currently the only work around would be to not use cake's `Folder` class :)  You could open a ticket (or better provide a patch) so the the method `Folder::isAbsolute()` (which controls whether realpath() should be used) returns true for path for registered stream wrappers.

Comment: I wrote the patch and send a pull request https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/3713
Looking forward to the feedback, this is my first time contributing to CakePHP :)